# How do i install the "nloptr" package correctly on my MAC?

Tags: r

I tried to install the "nloptr" package in R. (I have a Mac) I have "nlopt" already installed but still get the following error when I try to install "nloptr".

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘nloptr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-nloptr/00new/nloptr/libs/nloptr.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-nloptr/00new/nloptr/libs/nloptr.so, 6): Symbol not found: _nlopt_add_equality_constraint
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-nloptr/00new/nloptr/libs/nloptr.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-nloptr/00new/nloptr/libs/nloptr.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/nloptr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Possible help, though an imperfect resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47363578/3358272

Comment: Other discussions (mostly english) here: https://xbuba.com/questions/37425509