# Need help in building docker image from CRAN in Google cloud platform

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

See this docker file below.
The gcloud build "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" fails because of non-zero status from ‘nloptr’, ‘quantreg’, ‘lme4’, ‘car’, ‘rstatix’, ‘ggpubr’

Selected error message:

libtool: link: ERROR: no information for variable 'AR' cru .libs/libutil.a .libs/mt19937ar.o .libs/sobolseq.o .libs/timer.o .libs/stop.o .libs/redblack.o .libs/qsort_r.o .libs/rescale.o
../libtool: line 1102: ERROR:: command not found

Makefile:371: recipe for target 'libutil.la' failed

make[2]: *** [libutil.la] Error 127

make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpkxP7be/R.INSTALL49e01729d00b/nloptr/src/nlopt_src/util'

Makefile:574: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed

make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpkxP7be/R.INSTALL49e01729d00b/nloptr/src/nlopt_src'

Makefile:438: recipe for target 'all' failed

make: *** [all] Error 2

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘nloptr’

How can I solve this?

```
FROM gcr.io/gcer-public/shiny-googleauthrdemo:latest
MAINTAINER Mark Edmondson (r@sunholo.com)

# install R package dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ##### ADD YOUR DEPENDENCIES
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libxml2 \
    libxml2-dev \ 
    libproj-dev \
    libv8-dev \
    gsutil
    
## Install packages from CRAN
RUN install2.r --error \ 
    -r 'http://cran.rstudio.com' \
    ##### ADD YOUR CRAN PACKAGES
    nloptr \
    shiny \
    shinythemes \
    shinyjs\
    shinydashboard \
    readr \
    ggplot2 \
    DT \
    V8 \
    ggrepel \
    shinyWidgets \
    shinycssloaders \
    stringr \
    dplyr \
    plyr \
    tidyr \
    scales \
    ggpubr \
    shinycssloaders \
    plotly \
    ggExtra \
    tm \
    proj4 \
    ggalt \ 
    && rm -rf /tmp/downloaded_packages/ /tmp/*.rds

## copy your shiny app folder below
```

Comment: Could be an issue between R 3.X and 4.X? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900525/install-lme4-from-cran-on-ubuntu

Comment: Could be an issue between R 3.X and R 4.X https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900525/install-lme4-from-cran-on-ubuntu

Comment: Adding libnlopt-dev solve the nplotr issue, but still fails for ‘quantreg’, ‘lme4’, ‘car’, ‘rstatix’, ‘ggpubr’ @DavidBenkeser

Comment: Hi, hopefully the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425509/trouble-installing-nloptr-package-on-r-3-3-0 could be helpful to do troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks @ShafiqI!